# Function to return a number in array in expanded form?

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm

I've been stuck trying to create the function mentioned above for something I am working on

```js
function expandedForm(num: number): number[] {
  // ...
}

const k = expandedForm(8571);
console.log(k);
// [ 8000, 500, 70, 1 ]
```

Searching for this online only finds functions which return a string with `+` pluses between the numbers. Some help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the input using the remainder operator:

```js
function expandedForm(num: number): number[] {
  const arr: number[] = [];
  
  var x = num;

  // Iterate until `x` is greater than zero
  //
  // For each iteration, keep track of the `i`:
  // First iteration,  i == 0, 10^i == 10^0 == 1
  // Second iteration, i == 1, 10^i == 10^1 == 10
  // Third iteration,  i == 2, 10^i == 10^2 == 100
  // This variable will let you know the current decimal place
  for (var i = 0; x > 0; i++) {
    // Get the last digit of `x` by using the remainder operator
    const currentDigit = x % 10;

    // Insert to the array using the previous algorithm 
    arr.push(Math.pow(10, i) * currentDigit);

    // Remove the last digit of `x` using the floor of the division by 10
    x = Math.floor(x / 10);
  }

  // Reverse the array
  return arr.reverse();
}

const k = expandedForm(8571);
console.log(k);
```

Alternatively, you can insert to the first element of `arr`, without needing to reverse it in the end:

```js
function expandedForm(num: number): number[] {
  const arr: number[] = [];
  
  var x = num;

  for (var i = 0; x > 0; i++) {
    const currentDigit = x % 10;

    // Insert into the first element of `arr`
    arr.splice(0, 0, Math.pow(10, i) * currentDigit);

    x = Math.floor(x / 10);
  }

  // Just return the array
  return arr;
}

const k = expandedForm(8571);
console.log(k);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, next time, include your own attempt and explain how it's failing.

But since there is already a working answer here, I'll simply post my versions, which are both different from the above.

One approach is to do this mathematically, using recursion, and passing values of `8571` to `857`, then `85`, and finally `8`, adding the correct multiples of each power of ten to the running list.  It could look like this:

```js
const expandedForm = (n, p = 1, d = n % 10) =>
  n < 10
    ? [n * p]
    : expandedForm ((n - d) / 10, p * 10) .concat (d * p)

console .log (expandedForm (8571))
```

`p` here is the power of ten currently at play, and `d` is the final digit of the number.  `p` starts at `1` and we multiply by `10` at every step.

A second approach is to convert `n` to a string, split it into digits and then map each one to the appropriate multiple of a power of ten:

```js
const expandedForm = (n, [... ds] = String (n)) =>
  ds .map ((d, i) => d * 10 ** (ds .length - 1 - i))

console .log (expandedForm (8571))
```

Of the two, I prefer the elegance of the first, more mathematical, one.  But either works fine.

Note that both of these will leave zeros inside the output, so that, for instance, `8501` yields `[8000, 500, 0, 1]`. That may or may not be appropriate.  If you would rather get `[8000, 500, 1]`, then either of these is easy to fix:

```js
const expandedForm = (n, p = 1, d = n % 10) =>
  n < 10
    ? [n * p]
    : expandedForm ((n - d) / 10, p * 10) .concat (d > 0 ? d * p : [])
```

or

```js
const expandedForm = (n, [...ds] = String (n)) =>
  ds .filter (d => d !== '0') 
     .map ((d, i) => d * 10 ** (ds.length - 1 - i))
```

These last two variants have slightly different behaviors regarding a final zero digit; we could fix either up to match the other if desired.

Comment: Thanks, these other methods are cool especially the recursive one